# React checkbox is not getting checked

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a basic app in react. I have a checkbox for each item in the table and once if it is checked, I want to delete that item. But for now, I was just checking the working of checkbox. But my onChange is not triggering the handler function.

I have added a console log to my `handleOnChange` function, I can see it's not getting logged which means my '`onChange`' is not triggering the handler.

Here is my Table.js code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


function Table() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState([false]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadData = async () => {

            await axios.get('http://localhost:9000/')
                .then(function (res) {
                    setItems(res.data);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        }

        loadData();
    }, [items]);

    const handleOnChange = (index,e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Change event triggered");
        setIsChecked(prevState => {
            const newState = [...prevState];
            newState[index] = !newState[index];
            return newState;
        });

    };



    const ItemList = ({ items }) => {
        const listItems = items.map((item) => (
            <tr className="border border-slate-300">
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked={isChecked[item._id]} onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(item._id,e)} />
                </td>
                <td key={item.name}>
                    {item.name}
                </td>
                <td key={item.quantity}>
                    {item.quantity}
                </td>
                <td key={item.price}>
                    {item.price}
                </td>
            </tr>
        ));

        return (
            <>
                {listItems}
            </>
        );

    };




    return (
        <div className="grid grid-flow-col auto-rows-max max-w-full justify-center place-content-center">
            <table className="table-auto">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th className="border border-slate-300 ...">Checked</th>
                        <th className="border border-slate-300 ...">Items</th>
                        <th className="border border-slate-300 ...">Quantity</th>
                        <th className="border border-slate-300 ...">Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <ItemList items={items} />
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: You should pass `isChecked` to `<ItemList>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue might be the `isChecked` and how you are managing the `checked` prop of your input. The `isChecked` array is initialized as an empty array with a single false value and you're accessing `isChecked[item._id]` to determine the checked status.
Since the `isChecked` is initially `[false]` and this will not change in your code, `isChecked[item._id]` will be **`undefined`**.

You should `setIsChecked` when you're fetching the data:

```js
  // ...
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:9000/");
        setItems(res.data);
        setIsChecked(Array(res.data.length).fill(false));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };

    loadData();
  }, []);

  //...
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem. but when i have removed the `items` array of another setState from `useEffect`, the table is no longer getting updated. I have to refresh the page to see the changes. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `e.preventDefault()` inside the `onChange` handler. It makes you have to press the input twice to toggle on/off.

Also, try to make the row its own component.

```js
const { useCallback, useEffect, useState } = React;

const fetchData = () => Promise.resolve([
  { _id: 1, name: 'Foo', quantity: 1, price: 5.99 },
  { _id: 2, name: 'Bar', quantity: 2, price: 9.99 }
]);

const ItemRow = ({ _id, checked, handleOnChange, name, price, quantity }) => (
  <tr key={name} className="border border-slate-300">
    <td className="text-center">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="checkbox"
        checked={checked}
        onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(_id, e)} />
    </td>
    <td>{name}</td>
    <td className="text-right">{quantity}</td>
    <td className="text-right">{price}</td>
  </tr>
)

const ItemList = ({ handleOnChange, isChecked, items }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
  {
    items.map((item, index) => (
      <ItemRow {...item}
        key={item.name}
        checked={isChecked[index]}
        handleOnChange={handleOnChange} />
    ))
  }
  </React.Fragment>
);

const Table = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
      .then(data => {
        setItems(data);
        setIsChecked(Array.from(data, () => false));
      })
  }, []);

  const handleOnChange = useCallback((id, e) => {
    setIsChecked((prevState) => {
      const newState = [...prevState];
      const index = items.findIndex(item => item._id === id);
      newState[index] = !newState[index];
      return newState;
    });
  }, [items]);

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-flow-col auto-rows-max max-w-full justify-center place-content-center">
      <table className="table-auto">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="border border-slate-300 p-2">Checked</th>
            <th className="border border-slate-300 p-2">Items</th>
            <th className="border border-slate-300 p-2">Quantity</th>
            <th className="border border-slate-300 p-2">Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <ItemList
            handleOnChange={handleOnChange}
            isChecked={isChecked}
            items={items} />
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<Table />);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```